# UPDATE sql not affecting database

Tags: php, mysql, httprequest

I have this code. Its returning 1 but there is no change on the database!

```
<?
    include ("../connect.php");
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $stat = $_REQUEST['changeTo'];
    $prod = $_REQUEST['product'];

    echo mysql_query("UPDATE $prod SET STATUS = '$stat' WHERE ID = '$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
?>
```

Comment: Is anything being printed from `mysql_error()`?

Comment: **WARNING:** This code is massively open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: My first thought is that $id doesn't exist, can you manually enter an id that you know exists and try running that once? just to rule it out if nothing else

Comment: What does `mysql_affected_rows()` show? I'll bet it's 0, which means your WHERE clause isn't allow any rows to match.

Comment: rdlowrey: Yea you are right, its for my own use.. not public :)

Comment: k'leg: YOU GOT IT!! I just added some string to the id printing loop this morning.. Thanks guys!

Comment: @KrayyemAlthwaini I added my comment as an answer hoping to get credit for it, my rep is kinda low  :)

Comment: @KrayyemAlthwaini use mysql_affected_rows to check if an update has successfully updated the specified records. As said above me, successful updates (even with 0 changed rows) will return true (1). Glad you solved your problem. Cheers. (BTW, use prepared statements!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that $id doesn't exist, can you manually enter an id that you know exists and try running that once? just to rule it out if nothing else

I added this in the hopes that I could get an answer vote  :)

Comment: Wow for someone who didn't read the original comments it sounds like I am begging.

Answer (score 2):

An error will only be returned on an UPDATE statement if a SQL error occurs. If no rows are affected the query is still successful and reported as such.

Make sure all of the variables used in the query contain valid values and that the query should actually affect any records in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the SQL-Statement direct with values set by code.